# WaitOne with C# doesn't auto reset

Tags: c#, .net, events

Obviously the mistake has to be on my end:

```
var Event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
var T = new Timer(_ =>
{
    Console.Write("T");
    Event.Set();
}, null,  0, 10 * 1000);

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("W");
    Event.WaitOne();
}
```

The output of this code is:

> WTWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW[..]TWWWWWWWWWWWW...

The expected output is:

> WTWTWTWTWTWTWTWT

So, for some reason, once signaled the auto reset event doesn't seem to auto reset. What did I miss?

Comment: That's strange, I ran your code and it prints your expected result.

Comment: Are you sure your wrong output wasn't generated by the `ManualResetEvent`? Is so, that would be perfectly reasonable to get the `WTWWWWWWWWW[...]TWWWW` since it will only block once and everything else will happen irrespective of the lock unless you reset the event but for `AutoResetEvent[Slim]` you should get the desired output.

Comment: Please give us more background: which OS? which .NET Framework version? (or maybe Mono/Core?)

Comment: This is .net core 2.1 on Mac. The event does behave like a manual reset event, but it shouldn't. I event tried to manually reset the event just to see, but no change. At the same time, I have a hard time to believe this could be a bug because I imaging that these synchronization objects are probably used a lot and will have unit tests.